# WKWebView not responds when clicking an Ad. Console msg : [Accessibility] WKContentView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, webkit

I am using a `WKWebView` and I have set the `WKNavigationDelegate` methods and everything looks fine. The `delegate` methods respond as they should but not 100% as I would like.

There are some specific `ads` that are not clickable.

By saying `not Clickable` I mean that the

```
`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)`
```

is not getting fire.

And having an observer for the url to see at least what kind or `URL` is this still not getting a result from there.

```
mainWebView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.url), options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "estimatedProgress"{
            progressBar.progress = Float(mainWebView.estimatedProgress)
            print(Float(mainWebView.estimatedProgress))
        }
        if keyPath == #keyPath(WKWebView.url){
            print(mainWebView.url?.absoluteString)
        }

    }
```

The only thing I get is from the console which is

```
[Accessibility] WKContentView[@] set up: @ pid: @ MACH_PORT
```

Any idea..... or someone with similar issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should regist a handler like below:

```
[configuration.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"yourhandlerName"];
```